# UICollectionView: dynamic cell heights with UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistackview

I have a storyboard, consisting of a single `UICollectionView` with multiple cells, each of varying height. The first cell takes the height from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

.. but I'd like the second cell to be shorter.
I've placed two `UIStackViews` inside a "master" `UIStackView` inside the cell, and each of the inner `UIStackViews` has one or more labels, like this:

```
cell
--> stackView (master)
    --> stackView (1)
        --> label
    --> stackView (2)
        --> label
        --> label (etc)
```

.. in the hope that the `UIStackView` would make the cell height dynamic, but it doesn't. It takes the height from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as before.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute the size of the content for the `CollectionViewCell` and return it to the `sizeForItemAt` function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // Create an instance of the `FooCollectionViewCell`, either from nib file or from code.
    // Here we assume `FooCollectionViewCell` is created from a FooCollectionViewCell.xib
    let cell: FooCollectionViewCell = UINib(nibName: "FooCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        .instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
        .first as! FooCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the data for your `FooCollectionViewCell`
    cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(/*view1*/)
    cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(/*view2*/)

    // Layout the collection view cell
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutSubviews()

    // Calculate the height of the collection view based on the content
    let size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 0),
        withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired,
        verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel)

    return size
}
```

With this, you will have a dynamic cell heights `UICollectionView`.

---

Further notes:

1. for configuration of the collection view cell, you can create a helper function `func configure(someData: SomeData)` on `FooCollectionViewCell` so that the code could be shared between the `cellForItemAt` function and `sizeForItemAt` function.

   ```
   // Configure the data for your `FooCollectionViewCell`
   cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(/*view1*/)
   cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(/*view2*/)
   ```
2. For these two lines of code, it seems only needed if the `UICollectionViewCell` contains vertical `UIStackView` as subViews (likely a bug from Apple).

   ```
   // Layout the collection view cell
   cell.setNeedsLayout()
   cell.layoutSubviews()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to change the height of your cells you're going to have to change the height you return in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath.  The stack views aren't going to have any effect here.  Here's an example of what you can do:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return CGSizeMake(width, height/2)
    }
    return  CGSizeMake(width, height)
}
```

This will change the size of your cells at row 1.  You can also use indexPath.section to choose sections.  Hope this helps.